# How can I make an icon be separate to the left of the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text .
    </span>
```

See? that check icon is part of text and I don't want it. I want to put all text under each other vertically align (on the left side). How can I do that?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion with regard to exactly what you're looking for. If one of these answers helps you, please mark it as correct and upvote it. Otherwise, it might be worth clarifying your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a `display: flex;`

```css
span {
  display: flex;
}

i.fa-check {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text .
    </span>
```

Comment: This is correct, but not working in all browsers (specially mobile browsers) because of `flex` display.

Comment: What browser? I have used flex for years and haven't had issues in mobile. https://caniuse.com/#search=flex @MartinAJ

Comment: Really? I read somewhere it is not cross-browser as well. thank you anyway.

Comment: @MartinAJ It all depends on how far back you want to go? I would call those articles bullshit, support is good (check the link I added above). I done a couple of large sites with it, support back to IE11. Haven't used floats ever sense.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:block;` to the `.fa-check` in your css. That will make the checkmark be on a line of its own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your text inside some other element and lay out the icon and the text next to each other. That's most easily accomplished with `flex`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      <span>this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text .</span>
    </div>
```

Presumably you also want to add some padding to `.container` to make it look nicer.

**Edit:**

If you want to lay out the text *below* the check mark, you can just change the flex direction:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      <span>this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text .</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can float the icon right. I am showing you the way to do it with an inline style. You could also create a class that would have the line: float:right; in it.

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-check" style='float:right'></i>
      this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text this is a test text .
    </span>
```